# How to measure the relationship between two variables which are based on two different independent likert scales?

Tags: regression, correlation

I am looking for a statistical method which measures the relationship between two variables which are based on different likert scales and are independent from each other.

The first variable is a score which represents the pro-environmental behavior (PEB) (Likert Scale A)

The second variable represents the pereceived persuasiveness towards selected game design elements (Likert Scale B)

My aim is to show a relationship between the pro-environmental behavior score and the perceived persuasiveness (e.g. - Do people with a higher PEB - score perceived certain game design elements differently?)

I was thinking about a simple pearson correlation?

Furthermore, I have age and education, which may influence the PEB - score as well (this I want to show in a second step - probably through a multiple regression analysis).

Thank you.

Comment: agree with spearman rho. other thing you could look at is ordinal regression (for your multiple regression analysis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using likert scales which are ordinal rather than continuous I'd suggest using a spearmans rho as it can be used on ordinal data unlike pearson correlation

Comment: Also if I took a mean based of the likert scales?

Comment: Yes you shouldn't really be treating a Likert scale like a continuous one. A lot of researchers do. But it's not correct.

It'd be like trying to get the mean of 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th place. It wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Anything else I could possibly use appart from this?

Comment: I mean a spearmans rho is as easy to do as a pearson's one and is interpreted in much the same way.

Comment: Thank you, do I need to normalize it?

Comment: Nope that's the benefit of spearmans rho it is a nonparametric test and thus has no assumptions on the distribution of data.

My suggestion would be to perform both.

Comment: spearman's rho is pearson correlation on ranking of original data. but since the ordinal data is already ranked(?) they are the same? no?!